# I WANT TO CREATE TWO URL'S FOR SAME PRODUCT FOR MAGENTO 2

Tags: magento2.3.3, product-urls

I want to create two URLs for the same product, one URL that is with products SKU i.e. **https://domainname/skuNo.** And another URL is for SEO purpose i.e. **https://domain name/product name.html**
Where both URLs we can go to the same page.

**We are using MAGENTO 2.3**

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> **Try this :-**

Open `admin panel > Marketing > SEO & Search > URL Rewrites > Add URL Rewrites button`

**Example:-**

> select Create URL Rewrite -> **For Product**
>
> Request Path -> **skuNo**
>
> Target Path -> **catalog/product/view/id/700**
>
> Redirect Type -> **No**